# Connect HTML page with SQL server using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, sql-server, html, web-services

I have one HTML page in which I have 3 textbox fields **name**, **address**, **age** and I want to save data from these textboxes in my SQL server database.

I got one reference to perform this task by using web services but I was unable to connect with webservice from javascript.

So please help me by explaining the way for accessing web service from javascript **or** some other way (if present) to save data from HTML page to sql server.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I get query string values in JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115/how-can-i-get-query-string-values-in-javascript)

Answer (score 1):

```
<script>
var name=document.getElementById("name").value;
var address= document.getElementById("address").value;
var age= document.getElementById("age").value;

$.ajax({
      type:"GET",
      url:"http://hostname/projectfolder/webservicename.php?callback=jsondata&web_name="+name+"&web_address="+address+"&web_age="+age,
      crossDomain:true,
      dataType:'jsonp',
      success: function jsondata(data)
           {

            var parsedata=JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data));
            var logindata=parsedata["Status"];

            if("sucess"==logindata)
            {   
                alert("success");
            }
            else
            {
                alert("failed");
            }
          }  
    }); 
<script>
```

You need to use web services. In the above code I have php web service to be used which has a callback function which is optional. Assuming you know HTML5 I did not post the html code. In the url you can send the details to the web server.

Comment: A have a number of functions in my webservice. Tell me where to write particular function name that I want to invioke

Comment: Try writing those functions outside and make function calls as per you need from success parameter.

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript is a client-side language and your MySQL database is going to be running on a server.

So you have to rename your file to `index.php` for example (.php is important) so you can use php code for that. It is not very difficult, but not directly possible with html.

(Somehow you can tell your server to let the html files behave like php files, but this is not the best solution.)

So after you renamed your file, go to the very top, before `<html>` or `<!DOCTYPE html>` and type:

```
<?php
    if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
        /*Creating variables*/
        $name = $_POST["name"];
        $address = $_POST["address"];
        $age = $_POST["age"];


        $dbhost = "localhost"; /*most of the time it's localhost*/
        $username = "yourusername";
        $password = "yourpassword";
        $dbname = "mydatabase";

        $mysql = mysqli_connect($dbhost, $username, $password, $dbname); //It connects
        $query = "INSERT INTO yourtable (name,address,age) VALUES $name, $address, $age";
        mysqli_query($mysql, $query);
    }
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>.......
....
    <form method="post">
        <input name="name" type="text"/>
        <input name="address" type="text"/>
        <input name="age" type="text"/>
    </form>
....
```

Answer (score -1):

Before The execution of following code, I assume you have created a database and a table (with columns **Name (varchar), Age(INT) and Address(varchar)**) inside that database. Also please update your SQL Server name , UserID, password, DBname and table name in the code below.

In the code. I have used **VBScript** and embedded it in **HTML**.
Try it out!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/vbscript">
<!--    

Sub Submit_onclick()
Dim Connection
Dim ConnString
Dim Recordset

Set connection=CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
Set Recordset=CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
ConnString="DRIVER={SQL Server};SERVER=*YourSQLserverNameHere*;UID=*YourUserIdHere*;PWD=*YourpasswordHere*;DATABASE=*YourDBNameHere*"
Connection.Open ConnString

dim form1
Set form1 = document.Register

Name1 = form1.Name.value
Age1 = form1.Age.Value
Add1 = form1.address.value

connection.execute("INSERT INTO [*YourTableName*] VALUES ('"&Name1 &"'," &Age1 &",'"&Add1 &"')")

End Sub

//-->
</script>
</head>
<body>

<h2>Please Fill details</h2><br>
<p>
<form name="Register">
<pre>
<font face="Times New Roman" size="3">Please enter the log in credentials:<br>
Name:   <input type="text" name="Name">
Age:        <input type="text" name="Age">
Address:        <input type="text" name="address">
<input type="button" id ="Submit" value="submit" /><font></form> 
</p>
</pre>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Are you seriously suggesting placing your DB's user and password, for a user with permissions to insert, into an HTML document that can be viewed with any browser's devtools? O_O

That's no longer a security breach, that's just handing over your data to malicious actors, outright.